# Punctuation after conjunction like "or" and "and"

Tags: punctuation, parenthesis

I am wondering when we put commas, because in most situations after a conjunction we don't put a comma.

Example:

> This must be true or at least truer than the last proposition.

However, we may have a longer sentence.

> This must be true or at least, excluding some of the recent findings, truer than the last proposition.

Do we put a comma after findings and before excluding or not?

> This must be true or at least excluding some of the recent findings truer than the last proposition.

Comment: *"In most situations after a conjunction we don't put a comma."* That's only true of conjunctions with two items, and where it's the simple conjunction of two nouns. If you join two clauses together, a comma very often is used.

Answer (score 2):

The usage of commas in the second sentences is correct, not because of the conjunction, but because the words they enclose are a [parenthesis](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/parenthesis) in the sentence.

A parenthesis is an "explanatory word, phrase, or sentence inserted in a passage from which it is usually set off by punctuation". The punctuation in use is often commas, but may also be dashes or [brackets](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bracket).

Comment: What about the third sentence?

Comment: Omitting the commas makes this sentence difficult to parse. It is recommended to use punctuation.

Comment: The third sentence is overly complex for most writing environments. I’d strongly suggest breaking it into multiple smaller sentences unless you are writing in a deliberately obtuse style (e.g. some academic writing).

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how the sentence is constructed. It is not necessary to put comma before "and". Putting comma before "and" is called Oxford comma.

Comment: Usage of Oxford commas is required in some style guides and forbidden in some others. You need to follow the style that applies to the environment you are writing for.